# How to loop every 3 element in a PHP array?

Tags: php

I have following PHP array:

```
 $array = array( 'uname', '=', 'lizabd', 'pass',  '=', '225555')
```

now I want to loop every 3 element like this way

```
 uname = lizabd
 pass  =  225555
```

How can I do this?

I know I can slice it using this for the first element:

```
 $slice = array_slice($array, 3);
```

But how can I do this using Loop ?

Comment: what are your efforts??

Comment: I have used `array_slice()` but no luck

Comment: Use a [`for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) with step `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$array = array_chunk($array,3);

foreach($array as $arr){
  echo implode(' ',$arr);
  echo PHP_EOL; //for new line, you can also use echo '<br>';
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/970842

Reference:- [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)